# What's the best way to copy paste CSS id & class from Google Chrome Inspect Element?

Tags: css, class

MacBook PRO BTW; just want to copy + paste to css ids and classes into my text editor...

image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmkXe.png

Comment: cmd+c: copy / cmd+v: paste

Comment: Those aren't id's and classes, those are rules. And this isn't a development question.

Comment: You just made me think I was on the wrong se site again...

Answer (score 0):

This tool might be a big help with selectors for beginners:
http://selectorgadget.com/

Although, I recommend learning about the selectors here, it will make your life much easier later on when the time comes and you need to start using advanced selectors:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors